# BeautifyRuby works for .rb and not for .erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2, beautify-ruby

I am using ST2 on OSX 10.9.1. I have `htmlbeautifier` gem installed.I installed `BeautifyRuby` using `Package Control`. 
I have set the `ruby` path and file patterns in the Default Settings of `BeautifyRuby` as follows :

```
{
"tab_or_space": "space",
"ruby": "/Users/(username)/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby",
"file_patterns": ["\\.html\\.erb", "\\.rb", "\\.rake", "Rakefile", "Gemfile"],
"html_erb_patterns": ["\\.html\\.erb"],
"run_on_save": true,
"save_on_beautify": false
}
```

For me `BeautifyRuby` works for only files with extension `.rb` and not for files with extension `.erb`.

When i try to beautify a `.erb` file i get the following error :

```
"error: invalid output. check your ruby interpreter settings"
```

I also tried the same thing with manual installation of BeautifyRuby directly from git. Still gives me the same result.

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Comment: Not Really. I have already tried what you mentioned. I have updated the file patterns as well as installed htmlbeautifier. I will add the complete Default Setting for your reference.

Answer (score 13):

**If using rvm:**

1- In your BeautifyRuby.sublime-settings

> "ruby": "/Users/(user)/.rvm/rubies/ruby-(version)/bin/ruby"

2- Install htmlbeautifie in global gemset.

> ```
> rvm use (version)@global     
> gem install htmlbeautifier
> ```

This'll fix your problem..

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I have already done all this, as you can see in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using RVM. If you added a new ruby version and changed the RVM ruby deault, it will break the sublime BeautifyRuby package because your default ruby is now different from the one referenced in your BeautifyRuby setting.

First remove BeautifyRuby. Close sublime and re-open it then re-add the package.

Second, in your rails/ruby project folder, run `which ruby` and note the path.

Third, open `preferences > package settings > beautify ruby > settings default` and add the following:

```
{
...
"ruby":"path_printed_in_which_ruby_command",
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and I was able to resolve the issue by installing an older version of htmlbeautifier gem:

```
gem uninstall htmlbeautifier
gem install htmlbeautifier -v 0.0.12
```

It seems latest version of htmlbeautifier is not compatible with BeautifyRuby.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is several months old but I ran into the same problem and have a solution that worked for me that I think is worth sharing. In sublime text 3, under Preferences | Package Settings | BeautifyRuby | Settings - Default, the file_patterns value was corrupted slightly, merging .html and .erb file types together and in so doing breaking functionality for both of them.

What I found:

```
  "file_patterns": ["\\.html\\.erb", "\\.rb", "\\.rake", "Rakefile", "Gemfile"],
```

What I changed it to:

```
"file_patterns": ["\\.html", "\\.erb", "\\.rb", "\\.rake", "Rakefile", "Gemfile"],
```

That seemed to do the trick for me. Also, you'll want to make sure that the settings for 'ruby' are set to your current version of ruby, as mentioned above. Run 'which ruby' at the command line to get the current path to ruby on your machine, and use that value for your ruby setting. In my case it was:

```
"ruby": "/Users/bob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby",
```

(note there is a trailing comma at the end, since it's not the last config in the file).